# C++: retrieve map values and insert into second map

Tags: c++

I have one map within one header file class:

```
class One 
{
  // code
  typedef map<string, int> MapStrToInt;

  inline MapStrToInt& GetDetails(unsigned long index)
  {
    return pData[index];
  }

  // populate pData....

private:
  MapStrToInt *pData;
};
```

And a second class which implements another map and wants to get the first 10 details from the class One's map.

```
class Two
{
  // code

  One::MapStrToInt pDataTen;

  int function1()
  {
    for (int i =0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
      One::MapStrToInt * pMap = &(One::GetDetails(i));
      pDataTen.insert(pair<string, int>(pMap->first,pMap->second));
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile this, it states that pMap:
has no member named 'first'
has no member named 'second'

Any suggestions?

Thanks..

Comment: Are you sure that your code is correct? You call `One::GetDetails` like it was a static function, but it isn't. Also, what is your overall goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using pointers to your maps, instead of plain map objects. Thus, indexing them is the same as indexing into an array of maps. (This may actually be what you want, judging from your comments.)

However, `first` and `second` are members of an *element* within your map, not of the map itself. So you should [iterate over the map](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/begin/) to get its individual elements, then insert them into the second map.

Now, it is not quite clear whether you want to get 10 elements from the first map in your array, or 1 element each from 10 maps in your array. Here is how to do the former:

```
One::MapStrToInt& map = One::GetDetails(0);
MapStrToInt::iterator it = map.begin();

for (int i =0; i < 10 && it != map.end(); i++, it++)
{
    pDataTen.insert(*it);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
Each map in the original will have only 1 record as such, a string and int. So I just wanted to get these two values from the first 10 array elements and import these into a new map...

Answer (score 1):

`pMap` is a map. You need to define iterator to call first, second. 
You can call other map API's like insert, remove.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you might want to return a `pair<string, int>` from `One::GetDetails`. As it is, `One` must have an array of maps (not one map!), and this method returns one of those.

Comment: You are correct here.
This method should return 1 map from the array of maps. Should it not be able to get first and second from the returned map?

Comment: What is the "first" or the "second" of a map? Map iterators have first and second, not maps itself.

Comment: Then it is all very unclear what you want to do. Do you want to insert the contents of the first 10 maps into one map? One item from each of those 10 maps?

Comment: Yes. That's it.
I need to iterate over the retrieved map in order to get its info..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this function is not going to work:

```
inline MapStrToInt& GetDetails(unsigned long index)
{
    return pData[index];
}
```

The map is indexed on strings, not ints. The correct way to do this is to use an iterator. This is fairly generic code:

```
map <string, int> m; 
...  // populate
map <string, int> :: iterator it = m.begin();
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
   // do something with it->first and it->second
   ++it;
}
```